# Construct with a rule and compass a square, given one point from each side

Tags: geometry

> Construct with a ruler and compass a square, given one point from each side.
>
> [image: Square Deal]

I was reading the answer to [Square Deal](http://www.futilitycloset.com/2013/01/14/square-deal-5/), and I do not understand how the rest is easy to solve.  Could someone help me understand?  I don't see the square.

Comment: @Freddy, if it's not a Euclidean space, then what's a square?

Comment: Ah, Ok, I overlooked it.

Comment: It would be useful to include the partial solution given in the link, both for the convenience of readers here, and to prevent link rot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Connect $A$ and $C$ and draw a perpendicular from $B$ to this segment. Now construct $D’$  on this perpendicular such that $AC = BD’$. $DD'$ is one side of the square. (This construction is already given in the link provided)

Now to complete the square, draw perpendiculars from point $A$ and $C$ to the line $DD'$. And then draw a line passing though $B$ parallel to $DD'$.